# How to speed up my macro for clearing specific cell based on a string comparisson

Tags: performance, excel, cell, vba

I need to clear  cells value "noinfo" in a wide range (more 1000 rows). I use the macro mentioned below, but it's very slow. Maybe there is better way to perform this task?

```
For Each cell In Range("L2:N" & Range("N" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell.Value = "noinfo" Then cell.ClearContents
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that is much faster to copy all values to array, change array and them write them to range at once.

```
Dim values(), r As Long, c As Long
With Range("L2:N" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    values = .Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(values, 2)
             If values(r, c) = "noinfo" Then values(r, c) = Empty
        Next
    Next
    .Value = values
End With
```

Advantages:

- No screen updates or calculations until you write all values;
- Uses intrinsic data, not properties.

Comment: that's awesome!!! and one more question how could these empty cells be filled with formula?

Comment: Same as property `Value` apply to `Formula`.